# Java Operator confusion

Tags: java, operator-keyword

What is the difference between

```
+=
```

and

```
=+
```

in Java? I tried searching but got no results.

How do those two work specifically? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite easy:

`a+=b` is the same as `a = a+(b)`

`=+` simply does not exist.

However, you might see `a =+ b`. You should read it as `a = (+b)`. I.e., the parser will never parse `=+` as a single token, it will parse it as `=` and `+`, so the following expression may start with a plus. The same goes for `=-`:

```
int a =-b; // a = -b
int a =+b; // a = +b
```

Comment: So a+=b will go on until the condition for the loop is met correct?